# Drupal dropdown value changes

Tags: drupal, drop-down-menu, drupal-7

I have one unusual problem. I am creating a content type in Drupal that uses taxonomy term like dropdown menu, but I want another dropdown menu that changes its values according what I have selected in the first dropdown menu. How do I get that and where I need to store data for second dropdown menu. For now it would be excelet if its possible that the dat I need to show in second menu I write in when creating taxonomy term, I have done that it is like this:

- Taxonomy term 1

  - Add sub section 1
  - Add sub section 2
- Taxonomy term 2

  - Add sub section 3
  - Add sub section 4

When creating content type, for example I select Taxonomy term 1 and second dropdown menu values should be add sub section 1; add sub section 2.

I hope you understand the problem and its possible to do this kind of stuff. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module. This module will help you to add taxonomy field according to your requirement.

Please check the [demo](http://wimleers.com/demo/hierarchical-select/taxonomy) for this module.